# Using isalpha() leads to text dump

Tags: c, validation, loops, char, dump

I'm trying to use `isalpha()` to validate input and make sure it is not a letter. I've tried to use it properly, but I think I might be missing something.

The problematic part:

```
scanf("%i", &entry);

while (entry != 0) {

  if (isalpha(entry)) {
    printf("That isn't a number\n");
    printf("Please type a number or \"0\" to quit\n");
    scanf("%i", &entry);
  } else {
    // Do code stuff
  }
```

The code runs flawlessly when I use numbers, but when I put in a letter for `entry`, the code just dumps all the other lines. Do I have to redeclare `entry` as an int? Should I use a different loop? Should I validate the input another way?

Comment: Well, you specified a format mask for an integer.

Comment: In your question you say "is not a letter" but in the program you say "isn't a number". Did you mean to use `isdigit()`?

Answer (score 2):

[`isalpha`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isalpha.htm) checks if a character is a letter. It will return false when you enter an integer which does not correspond to the [ASCII value](http://benborowiec.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/better_ascii_table.jpg) of an alphabet provided that the entered integer is `EOF` or is in the range of an `unsigned char` or else,your code will exhibit Undefined Behaviour.

To fix your code,`entry` should be a `char` and `scanf` must use `%c` to scan it. Or else if you want `entry` to be a integer,check if `scanf` returns 0. If it does,`scanf` failed to scan an integer because user has entered something else. Your code will look like this:

```
while((scanf("%d", &entry))==0) //scanf failed to scan an int
{
    printf("That isn't a number\n");
    printf("Please type a number or \"0\" to quit\n");
    scanf("%*s");//remove the invalid character(s) from the stdin
}
```

Comment: Unless you really want the semantics of `%i` (for instance, reading `011` as octal for decimal `9` instead of decimal `11` with an extra leading `0`), it's best to use `%d`.

Comment: Changed `%i` to `%d` in the `scanf`

Comment: Thanks. This solution is absolutely perfect.

Comment: 1) "It will return false when you enter an integer which does not correspond to the ASCII value of an alphabet" misleads as `int` values outside `unsigned char` range and `EOF` is undefined behavior (UB) for `is...()` functions.  2) `isalpha()` corresponds to the encoding character set which often is `ASCII` but may be other character encodings - uncommon in 2014. 3) Interesting flush method with `scanf("%*s")`.

Comment: @chux , I did not know (1).BTW,is the maximum value of `unsigned char` 255?

Comment: The maximum value of `unsigned char` is `UCHAR_MAX` defined in `<limits.h>`.  By spec, it is _at least_ 255.  Confident it must always be a (power of 2) - 1.  Most compilers have it as 255, but exceptional ones use higher values.

Answer (score 1):

Invalid use of `isalpha()`

`int isalpha(int c)` is defined for for all `int` values in the `unsigned char` range and `EOF`.  Any other value leads to undefined behavior (UB).

When OP enters a letter for `scanf("%i", &entry)`, `scanf()` returns 0.  Unfortunately code did not check this return value.  Thus the value in `entry` is not defined and an errant value may be passed to `isalpha()`.

```
int entry;
int cnt;
cnt = scanf("%i", &entry);
if (cnt != 1) {
  printf("Integer not entered.  Returned count:\n", cnt);
} else if (((unsigned char) entry != entry) && (entry != EOF)) {
  printf("Integer entered is not in range.  entry::\n", entry);
} else if (isalpha(entry)) {
  printf("Character code %d is an alpha and is represented by %c\n", entry, entry);
} else {
  printf("Character code %d is not an alpha\n", entry);
}
```